# Powershell: An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: The specified directory service attribute or value does not e xist

Tags: powershell

I have been trying the following PowerShell script in several AD domain, but in one 2008 R2 domain it fails and I cannot find the reason for it:

```
PS D:\> Add-type -AssemblyName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
PS D:\> $ct = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType]::Domain
PS D:\> $Domain = $env:USERDOMAIN
PS D:\> $pc = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext   $ct,$Domain
PS D:\> $user = System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($pc, "SamAccountName", "testuser")
PS D:\> $groups = $user.GetAuthorizationGroups()
D:\> $groups
```

Normally the script gives a list of groups but for this domain it gives the following error message (after the list of groups):

An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

```
CategoryInfo:InvalidOperation(System.Director...ment.Principal]:FindResultEnumerator`1) [], Runtime
Exception
FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadEnumeration
```

Could this have anything to do with AD privileges or permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this could happen for a few possible reasons:

- While the groups are iterating, it tries to resolve the SID to an Active Directory object that does not exist. I would check out your Active Directory to make sure that there is no missing or broken AD users/groups. (Something like this error: [Microsoft Connect - Calling Principal GetAuthorizationGroups Error](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/522539/clr-forum-error-calling-principal-getauthorizationgroups-in-winxp-sp3))
- This could also be because of a Foreign Security principal that can't get resolved (Like this: [Foreign Security Groups in Active Directory](http://lucidcode.com/2013/02/18/foreign-security-groups-in-active-directory/))

Some possible solutions:

- Ignore the errors i.e. start off with `$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"`
- Try something like this:

(Very rough code as a starting point)

```
$searchRoot = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry
$adSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$adSearcher.SearchRoot = $searchRoot
$adSearcher.Filter = "(samAccountName=UserName)"
$adSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf")

$samResult = $adSearcher.FindOne()

if($samResult)
{
    $adAccount = $samResult.GetDirectoryEntry()
    $groupMembership = $adAccount.Properties["memberOf"]
    $groupMembership | foreach {
        Write-Host $_ 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, it was helpful in the troubleshooting. After removing one of the AD groups the script run without any error messages.

Comment: Great to hear! Glad you were able to find the problem.